# Can't setup @react-native-firebase/messaging in Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

i follow this [android setup doc of cloud messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/installation/android)

[image]

i have confused where to Add below code inside MainActivity class

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.asList(
    new MainReactPackage(),
    new ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
}
```

Currently My MainActivity class is :-
[image]

Please help me to Android Setup of @react-native-firebase/messaging.

```
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.6",
   "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.1",
   "react": "16.13.1",
   "react-native": "0.63.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside MainApplication.java

[image]

But as this package can be autolinked, you can avoid doing this step and just do:

`npx react-native run-android`